# Formatting grep output with awk. Simple case and background case

Tags: awk, pipe, buffer

I'm struggling with this problem. I have this line:

```
mplayer *.* 2>/dev/null | grep Playing
```

which just launchs `mplayer` and only the line matching `Playing filename` is printed on screen.
This works also every time I change currently played media.

I was wondering if it was possible to "format" the output of grep. For example, if the output is:

```
Playing Pink_Floyd-Wish_You_Were_Here.mp3  # I get this at the beginning
Playing Pearl_Jam-Once.mp3                 # I get this after I change media inside mplayer
```

then I would have something like:

```
Mplayer: Playing Pink_Floyd-Wish_You_Were_Here.mp3
Mplayer: Playing Pearl_Jam-Once.mp3
```

To do so, I decided to employ awk:

```
mplayer *.* 2>/dev/null | grep Playing | awk '{print "Mplayer: "$1}'
```

But in this case nothing happens; I get no output!!!

My question is not oriented to solve the problem with mplayer, but to have a deeper understanding about pipes in bash.

For example, if I use the following:

```
echo a_song.mp3 | awk '{print "Mplayer: "$1}'
```

I get what I want

```
Mplayer: a_song.mp3
```

Why does the first command not work?

What do I have to do if I want to run more than one process like this in background?

Comment: Did you have a single quote at the end of your first `awk` command?  What happens if you do `mplayer *.* 2>/dev/null | grep Playing > foo` and then `awk '{print "Mplayer: "$1}' < foo`?  Oh, BTW: `$1` means just the first word, so I would expect you to get "Mplayer: Playing".  You probably want `$0`.

Comment: Yes a single quote (the character '). I tried what you wrote. The obtained file foo is empty.

Comment: What you need is `mplayer Playing* 2>/dev/null  | awk '/Playing/{print "Playing: " $0}'` and you're done

Comment: Well, that doesn't make any sense; if `mplayer *.* 2>/dev/null | grep Playing` produces output to the terminal, then redirecting it to a file should get that same output.  Now you know where the problem is, and so where to focus your investigation.

Comment: @G-Man Thanks a lot. But please, be more precise, I'm quite a newbie into the bash world.

Comment: @val0x00ff: “My question is not oriented to solve the problem with mplayer, but to have a deeper understanding …”  So, while `mplayer *.* 2>/dev/null | awk '/Playing/ {print "Mplayer: " $0}'` (note that you have two errors in your suggestion) will fix *this particular problem*, it doesn’t explain why the command he tried produced no output.

Comment: @G-Man "Now you know where the problem is, and so where to focus your investigation." what you mean with this?

Comment: @the_candyman: As I said, the result you report doesn't make any sense; it's "impossible".  Try running `mplayer *.* 2>/dev/null | grep Playing` with output to the terminal, then again with output redirected to a file, and then again with output to the terminal, and see if you can make sense of what's happening.

Comment: @val0x00ff thanks a lot for your solution. Anyway, I would like to understand what's wrong with my bash code

Comment: @G-Man ok, I retried. The first time I stopped mplayer using CTRL+C. I repeted the "experiment" and closed mplayer window with mouse. Now the foo file is filled! Why this? What's next now?

Comment: @G-Man why is the `print` wrong?  And to solve his particular problem and if I had to remain in his way of thinking e.g  `mplayer *.* 2>/dev/null | stdbuf -oL grep "Playing" |awk '{print "Playing: " $0}'`  would do what he wants.

Comment: @the_candyman there is no bash code in your example.  You are using external commands `player` , `grep` , `awk`. You have problems with buffering.  This page will explain everything about it: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009?highlight=%28unbuffer%29

Comment: @val0x00ff great, I think I'm starting to understand! I've used the --line-buffer option for grep. Just for curiosity, how do I use fflush function with awk? I have tried awk '{print "Mplayer: "$1; fflush()}' but nothing happens...

Comment: @val0x00ff: Your `print` command is wrong in that the question asks for `print "Mplayer: "…` and you gave him `print "Playing: " …`

Comment: @the_candyman: It's `grep` buffer problem, not `awk`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many [grep](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) implementation will use line buffered when standard output is terminal. When standard output is terminal, it's often an interactive session, you want to get data as soon as possible. So `grep` will write data to standard output as soon as seeing a newline.

When standard output isn't terminal (often meaning non-interactive session), `grep` will use block buffer instead. It means `grep` doesn't write to standard output immediately when seeing a newline. `grep` collects amount of data (4096 bytes in Linux) before writing to standard output.

Some `grep` version, like [GNU grep](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) or [BSD grep](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/grep.1.html) have [--line-buffered](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#index-g_t_002d_002dline_002dbuffered-126) option. It make `grep` always writing to standard output when seeing a newline. So your example become:

```
mplayer *.* 2>/dev/null | grep --line-buffered Playing | awk '{print "Mplayer: "$1}'
```

If your `grep` version doesn't have `--line-buffer`, you can do it all with `awk`:

```
mplayer *.* 2>/dev/null | awk '/Playing/{print "Mplayer: "$1}'
```

---

GNU coreutils has a tool [stdbuf](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html) for modifying buffering of command. You can always force line buffer in standard output with:

```
stdbuf -oL command
```

There's also [unbuffer](http://expect.sourceforge.net/example/unbuffer.man.html) command which disables the output buffering only.

**Further reading**

- [stdio buffering](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/)
- [BashFAQ/009](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009)